# How to correctly set the TTL for MQTT messages to expire on ThingsBoard?

Tags: javascript, c++, mqtt, thingsboard, ttl

In order for MQTT messages to expire after a certain amount of time in ThingsBoard a Time-to-Live (TTL) parameter can be added to the message. Inside the ThingsBoard rule chains more logic can be added. For the TTL to work it is necessary to add it to the metadata.

The typical workflow in ThingsBoard's Rule Chain is:

1.Message received by the Input node.
2.Metadata and data are split.
3.Nodes process both separately.

The topic used is: `v1/devices/me/telemetry`
The data format of the payload looks like this: `{"ts":1451649600512, "values":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}}`

How do I correctly add the TTL to the message so it works in ThingsBoard? I want certain messages to expire after a time, based on the contents of the message.

As I understand it, the TTL needs to be added in the metadata or it will not work.

I previously used a JavaScript node in the rule chain to accomplish this. Based on the content of the message a line would be added in the script:

```
if(typeof msg.Alive !== 'undefined'){
metadata.TTL = "45";
}

return {msg: msg, metadata: metadata, msgType: msgType};
```

This seemed to work. The problem that arose however is the limitation that is set on the amount of JS script executions. Doing it via the rule chain means that this limit is reached rather quickly.

So the previous solution is not feasible when using a lot of devices. What is the correct way to do the above in ThingsBoard without using JS?

Our new approach was to include the TTL inside the message payload, such as  `{"ts":1451649600512, "TTL": 15, "values":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}}`. The assumption was that the TTL would be picked up as metadata, just like the timestamp is. This seemed not to be the case. Adding it to ‘values’ aka the data, made it show up in the ThingsBoard data, but didn’t solve our problem.

Comment: One possible solution is to use TBEL inside ThingsBoard. For scripts in the nodes you can choose between JS and TBEL. There is a significant difference in the cost: The TBEL execution consumes 100 times fewer resources for us.

Although this will work, I hope I find a better way still.

Comment: Have you tried deploying multiple JS Executors to reduce the JS execution bottleneck? see here - https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/msa/#javascript-executor-microservices . I'm assuming your hosting/deployment scenario is private and not one of the TB Cloud solutions.